# Css : Handle two flexbox that can overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I must handle a case where I want to display on one line a value, a category and the number of concerned item in the following format.

[ Item name ] ([ Path start ], [ Item count ])

Example : My item value (My category, 5)

My issue is that the item name and the path start can be too long. I listed the different case in the following drawing

[image: img]

And I can't find a way to handle all the case using CSS only. My biggest issue is to fix the size of the two flex-box when they are both overflowing.

The closest version I have now is the following (you can un-comment the max-width to see an other result I have):

Code:

```css
.search_list {
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  
   /* only for exemple */
  width: 400px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.search_info {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 30%;
  /*max-width:30%;  Get rid of this */
}
.search_info .flex {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.search_info .no_flex {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.search_value {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  flex: 1 1 70%;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="search_list" >
  <div class="search_value">Short values</div>
  <div class="search_info">
    <div class="flex">(Category</div>
    <div class="no_flex">, 1)</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search_list" >
  <div class="search_value">Item value with a long long text that overlow</div>
  <div class="search_info">
    <div class="flex">(Category</div>
    <div class="no_flex">, 1)</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search_list" >
  <div class="search_value">Long category</div>
  <div class="search_info">
    <div class="flex">(The category will overflow for sure in this case</div>
    <div class="no_flex">, 1)</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="search_list" >
  <div class="search_value">Long category and text that will both overflow</div>
  <div class="search_info">
    <div class="flex">(The category is very</div>
    <div class="no_flex">, 1)</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But, as you can see, this is not the intended results

I tried many things but I can't find a correct solution and I don't want to do thinks like counting the number of character to do a manual overflow and I also would like to avoid JavaScript since this is for a project in Web-assembly and it's a bit annoying to use JavaScript

Comment: Not clear what is the end result, You want text to always be on display no matter what length it might be and the containers to shrink and expand to accommodate it ? is the `400px` width constraint a must ? did you try `inline-flex` rather than just `flex` ? if you want fit a ton of text in a small space you have two options, lower the font size which not optimal, or overflow scroll to be able to read it.

Comment: I don't want to have a scroll. The `400px` constraint is set in another way in the complete project but there is a fixed width. The idea is to display all the text if possible, but if this is too big, I want the to part to have overflow and fixed sized like I showed in the picture.

Comment: I will explain with the right part, it can be as big as necessary as long as the left part can be displayed fully. it can also go under 30% width if it's a short text. But the width must be 30% if both of the part are overflowed
@ZohirSalak (Forgot to mention in the last comment)